# Angular2 - Component variable value set on callback function not updated in template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, google-geolocation

User case: When application is opened in web browser, user gets alter- "Know your location" with options "Allow" and "Deny".

I have following code sample.

```
ngOnInit() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      this.zoom = 18;
    });
  }
}
```

this works as I can see console.log that the final values of latitude and longitude is current location if allowed otherwise it is the default value which I hard coded.

Now my problem here is this updated current location changes cannot be seen in template when it print `{{latitude}}`  and `{{longitude}}`

I have tried using `ngZone` and `ChangeDetectorRef` but was no success

Can anyone help

Comment: It works for me without using ngZone

Comment: Interesting. I thought `geolocation` is one of the examples where zone is required. Did they fix it in zone.js (didn't follow the development)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geolocation API is not covered by Angulars zone.
Make the callback run inside Angulars zone explicitely and Angular change detection will be run and ensure the view is updated:

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

ngOnInit() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {                
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 18;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the exact same code but it's not working for me :(

Comment: As yurzui explained it shouln't even be necessary. Please create a plunker that allows to reproduce the problem.